# Sending data generated from a seperate python program to socketIO clients with a socketIO server

Tags: python-socketio

I currently have a socketio webserver using WSGI and I host it with gunicorn. I also have set up a javascript client which uses a web browser. I've managed to get these two to be able to communicate.

I'm working on creating an information service which takes events which happen in a game from a log and then parses it through a seperate python script to create a readable GUI. But that bit doesn't really matter.

Once I have my string of text from my seperate python program, how do I send it to all clients connected to my webserver? The program isnt part of the socketIO server so, as far as I'm aware, can't use emit().

My idea was to create a seperate python client which connected to the socketio server and do it that way. I've illustrated the flow below:

- socketIO python Client -- DATA --> socketIO server
- socketIO server -- DATA --> ALL socketIO clients.

I'm struggling to be able to work out a way to perform this? Could anyone help or suggest a more efficient way? Let me know if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: Have you read the section of the documentation on emitting from an external process? https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#emitting-from-external-processes

Comment: No, I didn’t see that in the documentation. I’ll take a look at that. Thanks Miguel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Miguel, I hadn't seen that in the documentation. Despite reading it over and over, I was stuck for a while. My stupid mind didn't come across the thought that I'd need to install Redis-server...

All working now!

Lesson learned: check requirements for my program...